# How to overlap 2 css items and make 1 item go to forefront

Tags: html, css

I would like to achieve the following: I have a css grid layout, and I want the splash image to overlap the navigation bar, with the navigation bar on the forefront. I can bring the image to the top by using grid-row-start: 1; on it, but then the navigation bar seems to move to the next item or something.

```css
#container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
    grid-template-rows: 50px 600px 1200px 50px;
}

#headerImage{    
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
#header{
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 1;   
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 1;
}

nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    width: 150px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
        <div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li>text1</li>
                <li><img id="splashimage" src="images/splashimage.png" /></li>
                <li>text2</li>
            </ul>
        </div >
        <div id="header"><img id="headerImage" src="images/header.jpg" /></div>
        <div id="content">

        </div>


        <div id="footer">

        </div>
    </div>
```

How do I achieve this? Thanks.

[image: website]

Answer (score 0):

You can use z-index css property for the image to overlap the navigation bar
You have to declare one class in the image tag , let it be splashimage,

```
.splashimage {
    z-index: 100
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use z-index and you can also do it using position property.
I have done a very small example on w3school. please see the attached screenshots
[image]